# static method vs non-static method

Tags: php, class, oop, methods, static

Below are the examples of php class code that is static method and non static method.

Example 1:

```
class A{
    //None Static method
    function foo(){
        if (isset($this)) {
            echo '$this is defined (';
            echo get_class($this);
            echo ")<br>";
        } else {
            echo "\$this is not defined.<br>";
        }
    }
 }

 $a = new A();
 $a->foo();
 A::foo();

 //result
 $this is defined (A)
 $this is not defined.
```

Example 2:

```
class A{
    //Static Method
    static function foo(){
        if (isset($this)) {
            echo '$this is defined (';
            echo get_class($this);
            echo ")<br>\n";
        } else {
            echo "\$this is not defined.<br>\n";
        }
    }
 }

 $a = new A();
 $a->foo();
 A::foo();

 //result
 $this is not defined.
 $this is not defined.
```

I am trying to figure out what is the difference between these two Classes.

As we can see on the result of the none static method, the "$this" was defined.

But on the other hand the result on the static method was not defined even they were both instantiated.

I am wondering why they have different result since they were both instantiated?

Could you please enlighten me on what is happening on these codes.

Comment: Because static methods are callable without instantiating. So $this is not available

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using $this inside static methods and methods called by this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722059/using-this-inside-static-methods-and-methods-called-by-this-method)

Comment: now i understand why the result is not defined on static method, instead of using $this on static method should be used "self". am i right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before we go any further: Please, get into the habbit of *always* specifying the visibility/accessibility of your object's properties and methods. Instead of writing

```
function foo()
{//php 4 style method
}
```

Write:

```
public function foo()
{
    //this'll be public
}
protected function bar()
{
    //protected, if this class is extended, I'm free to use this method
}
private function foobar()
{
    //only for inner workings of this object
}
```

first off, your first example `A::foo` will trigger a notice (calling a non-static method statically always does this). 
Secondly, in the second example, when calling `A::foo()`, PHP doesn't create an on-the-fly instance, nor does it call the method in the context of an instance when you called `$a->foo()` (which will also issue a notice BTW). Statics are, essentially, global functions because, internally, PHP objects are nothing more than a C `struct`, and methods are just functions that have a pointer to that struct. At least, that's the gist of it, [more details here](https://wiki.php.net/internals/engine/objects)

The main difference (and if used properly benefit) of a static property or method is, that they're shared over all instances *and* accessible globaly:

```
class Foo
{
    private static $bar = null;
    public function __construct($val = 1)
    {
        self::$bar = $val;
    }
    public function getBar()
    {
        return self::$bar;
    }
}
$foo = new Foo(123);
$foo->getBar();//returns 123
$bar = new Foo('new value for static');
$foo->getBar();//returns 'new value for static'
```

As you can see, the static property `$bar` can't be set on each instance, if its value is changed, the change applies for all instances.
If `$bar` were public, you wouldn't even need an instance to change the property everywhere:

```
class Bar
{
    public $nonStatic = null;
    public static $bar = null;
    public function __construct($val = 1)
    {
        $this->nonStatic = $val;
    }
}
$foo = new Bar(123);
$bar = new Bar('foo');
echo $foo->nonStatic, ' != ', $bar->nonStatic;//echoes "123 != foo"
Bar::$bar = 'And the static?';
echo $foo::$bar,' === ', $bar::$bar;// echoes 'And the static? === And the static?'
```

Look into the factory pattern, and (purely informative) also peek at the Singleton pattern. As far as the Singleton pattern goes: Also google why *not* to use it. IoC, DI, SOLID are acronyms you'll soon encounter. Read about what they mean and figure out why they're (each in their own way) prime reasons to *not* go for Singletons

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you need to use a method but you don't want call class, because some functions in a class called automatically like as __construct, __destruct,... (Magic Methods).

**called class:**

```
$a = new A();
$a->foo();
```

**Don't called class:** (just ran foo() function)

```
A::foo();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: if you want to call a function, but don't want to call a constructor/destructor, don't declare that function as a method...